# Derive istringstream and implementing operator>>(string&)

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, multiple-inheritance

I'm dealing with the following situation:
I'm using istringstream's operator>> to extract formatted data within template function.
Every thing work great except when the function is called with std::string which has space.
e.g. std::string tmp("bla tmp");
As everybody knows there is a an operator>> (not a member of istringstream) that takes istream and string and extracts data using spaces as delimiters.
So I'm getting the following "bla" instead of "bla tmp".
To make ling story short, I tried to be sophisticated and did the following:

```
class MyClass : public istringstream{
public:
      MyClass(const char* st) : istringstream(st){}
      void operator>>(string& st){st = this->str();}
}
```

But now I'm facing this problem:

```
MyClass my("bla tmp");
string tmp;
my >> tmp; // now tmp == "bla temp" and this is exactly what I wanted
//but this does not work
int kk;
my >> kk; //gives me "no match for operator>>"
```

How can it be ?!
istringstream inherits operator>> for basic type from istream and I inherit from istringstream.
But by implementing my own operator>> and by that extending istringstream as a result MyClass looses operator>> for basic types.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can it be ?! istringstream inherits operator>> for basic type from istream and I inherit from istringstream.

Your overload of `operator >>` *hides* the one in the base class. You should use a `using` declaration to make the overloads of `operator >>` from the base class participate to overload resolution:

```
class MyClass : public std::istringstream {
public:
    using std::istringstream::operator >>;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    MyClass(const char* st) : std::istringstream(st){}
    void operator>>(std::string& st){st = this->str();}
};
```

The concept of name hiding and how it interferes with overload resolution is explained in [this article by Herb Sutter](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/22/gotw-5-solution-overriding-virtual-functions/?utm_source=tf&utm_medium=t) (although the article is mainly about virtual functions, it does discuss the exact same problem you are facing).

Finally, here is a [**live example**](http://ideone.com/TFOTal) of your code compiling with the above change.